# Can a notation for ordered pairs in ZFC set theory be introduced as a conservative extension of ZFC without junk theorems?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Currently, a standard way to introduce ordered pairs in **ZFC** set theory is to define
an ordered pair $(a,b)$ as $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$. From this definition one can deduce the main property of ordered pairs:
$(a,b) = (x,y) \rightarrow a=x \,\&\, b=y$.

But some junk theorems can also be proved, for example, $(a,a) = \{\{a\}\}, \{a\} \in (a,b)$, etc.

see also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90820/set-theories-without-junk-theorems

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/386756/a-better-way-to-introduce-ordered-pairs-in-zf

For a different approach see the paper "Adding an Abstraction Barrier to ZF Set Theory"

https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-030-53518-6_6.pdf

An excerpt from it:

" Such ‘accidental theorems’ do not match how people think about the mathematics and also cause practical difficulties when using set theory in machine-assisted theorem proving."

So a natural question arises: is it possible to introduce ordered pairs in a more safe way, without possibility to get
such strange "theorems".

A rather natural approach is to extend **ZFC** just by adding a new function symbol (say $\pi$, it is usually omitted)
and a defining axiom such as  $\pi(a,b) = \pi(x,y) \rightarrow a=x \,\&\, b=y$
and prove that such theory extension is conservative (without such proof we can get an undesirable result, in a worse case - an inconsistent theory).

So my question:

Is this extension of **ZFC** (by adding the function symbol $\pi$ and its defining axiom)  conservative?

Comment: Would a combination of extensionality and the pair axiom count as a "junk theorem", i.e. $\forall x,y,x',y', (\forall z, z \in (x,y) \leftrightarrow z \in (x',y')) \rightarrow x=x' \land y=y'$?

Comment: You seem to have asked this recently on MO as well:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/386756/a-better-way-to-introduce-ordered-pairs-in-zf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, in the strongest possible sense: if $M\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ then $M$ has an expansion to a model $M'$ of the theory you describe (that is, there is an $M'$ satisfying your theory whose *reduct* to $\{\in\}$ is exactly $M$ itself). Specifically, any of the usual set-theoretic implementations of ordered pairs can be taken to be $\pi^{M'}$.

- EDIT: in response to a comment below, let me explain in detail *why* this fact about extensions implies conservativity. Suppose your theory were to prove some sentence $\varphi$ purely in the language of set theory (i.e. no reference to $\pi$). I claim $\mathsf{ZFC}$ must already prove that sentence. For otherwise take some $M\models\mathsf{ZFC}+\neg\varphi$. By the previous paragraph it has some expansion $M'$ satisfying your theory. But since your theory entails $\varphi$ this means $M'\models \varphi$. But $M$ is the reduct of $M'$ to the language of pure set theory, so we get $M\models\varphi$ as well, a contradiction.

This may feel silly but it's not: we avoid junk theorems about $\pi$ even if we consider such expansions because of the **different ways** ordered pairs can be implemented in set theory. E.g. considering the difference between the Kuratowski ordered pair $\langle a,b\rangle_{K}=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ and the Hausdorff ordered pair $\langle a,b\rangle_H=\{\{a,1\},\{b,2\}\}$ we have that neither $\forall x(\{x\}\in\pi(x,x))$ nor $\exists x(\{x\}\not\in\pi(x,x))$ is a theorem of the new system.

Comment: I don't really follow your second paragraph. Because you can code ordered pairs in more than one way, you don't have any junk theorems about them in the expanded language. But then in a given model the ordered pairs *are* implemented as sets, so "is $x\in (a,b)$ true?" is still a "valid question to ask". The correct approach is to say that we actually don't care about ordered pairs, and instead we prove a "template theorem" where we plug-in definitions for ordered pairs and get structural theorems.

Comment: @AsafKaragila My claim in the second paragraph is exactly that we don't have any junk theorems in the expanded theory; this is not contradicted at all by junk sentences holding in certain models of that expanded theory (or even more precisely every model satisfying some junk sentence!).

Comment: Yeah, but junk theorems are not *really* about the Kuratowski coding, because then we could have just collectively agree to use some other coding. The complaint is about "weird statements" like $0\in(1,2)$ even making sense. Those complaints are *dumb*, and they are an artifact of understanding that coding, of any kind, leads to "junk statements".

Comment: @AsafKaragila That's not what the body of the question actually says anywhere: as written, it just asks for no junk theorems to be proved in the system. I do think I've answered the question as posed, although you're very likely right that the OP may actually want more.

Comment: @Noah Schweber  Suppose, you are writing a handbook on Set Theory. How you would introduce ordered pairs?

Comment: @vmak It would depend on my audience.

Comment: @Noah Schweber Suppose your  audience are set theory students. Would you place a remark that ordered pairs can be introduced in a safe mode, without junk theorems?

Comment: @vmak It would be harder to work with and set theory wouldn't gain anything from it. For example how do you prove that $V_\alpha$ for limit $\alpha$ satisfies pairing? I you want to use some global function $\pi$, then this might not be true. The Kuratowski definition doesn't push the rank up to much, which is a very nice and desirable property in set theory. These sort of details can make life easier.

Comment: @AsafKaragila "Those complaints are *dumb*", well, let's not start throwing names around here :-) They may be unfounded worries, but for people at a certain stage of understanding of set theory, they seem like reasonable questions to ask.

Comment: @David: I'm not saying that it's not something to worry about for three seconds at some point. But it's a dumb thing to worry about. It's the worry that there's a monster under the bed. Besides, smart people can have dumb worries, it happens all the time, and there's no need to be ashamed of that.

Comment: @Noah Can you please explain in detail why the extension is conservative?

Comment: @vmak If every model of a theory $T$ in a language $\Sigma$ can be expanded to a model of a larger theory $T'\supseteq T$ in a larger language $\Sigma'$, then obviously $T'$ cannot prove any $\Sigma$-sentences which $T$ itself couldn't prove: if $\varphi$ is a $\Sigma$-sentence with $T'\vdash\varphi$ but $T\not\vdash\varphi$, then there is a model of $T$ satisfying $\neg\varphi$ which cannot be expanded to a model of $T'$, contrary to the original assumption.

Comment: @vmak I've added to say a bit about this in the body of the answer itself.

Comment: @Noah Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Whatever we want of ordered pairs is absolutely not only the famous implication. I believe that (a,b) being Goedel-constructible in a,b is a sine qua non in set theoretic practice above 5 or so introductory lectures, and so is (a,b) being easily coded by a real provided a,b are reals, and zillion more such properties. So an abstract non-definable Bourbaki-style pair in the language will not work.

Comment: +1. Just to clarify for the OP, this answer **does not** contradict the other answers. The point here is not that the extension is not conservative, it obviously is, it's that it's not a *good framework* for what set theorists actually want to do with pairing functions beyond very elementary constructions.

Comment: +1 from me too, but it needs to be stressed that most mathematical users of set theory are not interested in set theory, and for them, the abstract properties are what matter: $e \subset \pi$ is true, if you construct the reals using one-sided, downward-closed Dedekind cuts, but is nonsensical to most mathematicians. Benacerraf's [What Numbers Could Not be](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2183530?seq=1) is essential reading, in this connection.

Comment: Regarding the $e\subseteq\pi$ trashtalk. I have no idea about the height of Trump and Biden. Suppose for the sake of discussion that it's resp. 178 and 182 cm. Then Biden is taller than Trump. Does this observation have any relevance for electoral events? Not at all. Is this a reason to claim that Trump and Biden have no height whatsoever?

Comment: Why do you call the statement $e \subseteq \pi$ "trashtalk"? Your comments about Trump and Biden and their height seem to me to be completely irrelevant.

Comment: Trashtalk is categorical speculations about $e\subset\pi$, not the (trivial wrt the Dedekind formalization) formula itself.

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed conservative. We can prove that it is conservative quite simply. In fact, it's easy to show that $ZFC + \pi + Q$ is conservative, where $Q$ is the axiom $\forall a \forall b (a, b) = \pi(a, b)$.

This follows from a general result in logic which states the following: consider a theory $T$ and a statement $P$, where $FV(P) \subseteq \{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n, y\}$. Suppose that $T \vdash \forall x_1 \forall x_2 ... \forall x_n \exists ! y P$. Then consider the new theory $T$, which is $T$ with added $n$-ary function symbol $f$ and axiom $\forall x_1 \forall x_2 ... \forall x_n P[y \mapsto f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)]$, where $[y \mapsto f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)]$ is capture-avoiding substitution. Then $T'$ is a conservative extension of $T$.

Therefore, $ZFC + \pi$ is conservative.